# C# Razor: How to update model property value in view?

Tags: c#, razor

How do I update my model property value that is bound in my view when I toggle a button? Can this be done in Razor without having to use JQuery/Javascript? I am attempting to conditionally display/hide a div (validation message) and bind a model property value if the div is displayed (ie. if `StoreExists === false`). Right now it is only binding on page load. This my code below:

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetStoreSettings(Form form)
        {
            string storeNumber= form.StoreNumber;
            bool isStoreFranchise= form.IsStoreFranchise
            Model.SetStoreType(storeNumber, isStoreFranchise);
            return Json(Model);
        }
```

**Model:**

```
public string StoreType { get; set; }
public bool StoreExists { get; set; }

public void SetStoreType(string storeNumber, bool isFranchiseSelected)
        {     
            if (storeNumber == String.Empty &&  isFranchiseSelected)
            {
                StoreType = "franchise";
            }
            else if (storeNumber == String.Empty && !isFranchiseSelected)
            {
                StoreType = "corporate";
            }
            else
            {
                StoreExists = true;
            }            
        }
```

**View:**

```
@if (!Model.StoreExists)
            {
                <div>@($"There is no {Model.StoreType} store for this state")</div>
            }
```

Comment: C# code gets executed on the server and resulting HTML markup gets sent to the browser. So if you need dynamic behavior, you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. Thank you.